# The Moon and the Great Wall

Tags: knowledge, pattern, letters, anagram, connect-wall

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/)</sub>

---

**Instructions for this modified connecting wall:**

> 1. In the connecting wall below, each item as written contains **one letter too many**. Once this spare letter is removed, the real word to be categorised is an **anagram** of the remaining letters.
> 2. Appropriately categorise these anagrams into four groups of four, as per your standard connecting wall. The themes for each category are... well, you'll work it out soon enough... The four spare letters for each group can then be anagrammed into a **real four-letter word**. (In some cases, more than one anagram is possible - you will need to deduce the intended one when working through Step 3 below...)
> 3. These four four-letter words are in turn linked by one final (contextually appropriate) **five-letter word - what is it?**

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABORTION | CHIANG MAI | DURIANS | ESPECIAL |
| FEDERAL | IN THE CLEAR | MALISM | MOULDED |
| OH DEAR | OINKED | ONRUSH | PETUNIAS |
| PRETORIUS | SERAPH | SYNDICATE | TITIAN |

Comment: 1k rep left to go!! :) Aka 1 week for you :P

Comment: Unfortunately I don't participate in this site due to my bad puzzles and puzzle solving, but go Stiv! :D

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil 12 days in the end - sorry for not living up to your high expectations ;-)

Comment: @Stiv I guess you could say, it took ‘longer than usual’ :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is truly the Moon and the Great Wall!

The groups are

> [Moons of Saturn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moons_of_Saturn):
>  malism -l = **MIMAS**
>  titian -i = **TITAN**
>  oinked -k = **DIONE**
>  petunias -n = **IAPETUS**
>
>  [Great Lakes of North America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Lakes)
>  onrush -s = **HURON**
>  chiang mai -a = **MICHIGAN**
>  pretorius -t = **SUPERIOR**
>  abortion -b = **ONTARIO**
>
>  [Monarchs known as the Great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_known_as_the_Great)
>  in the clear -l = **CATHERINE**
>  durians -n = **DARIUS**
>  oh dear -a = **HEROD**
>  federal -e = **ALFRED**
>
>  Words associated with Lunar
>  especial -a = **ECLIPSE**
>  syndicate -y = **DISTANCE**
>  moulded -d = **MODULE**
>  seraph -r = **PHASE**

This gives the four four-letter words

> **KILN**, **BATS**, **LANE** and **YARD**
>  which are linked by the word
>  **BRICK**
>  as is, of course, also the final word of the title, WALL.

Comment: Perfectly found, great job :) I'm really pleased you chose the K___ anagram too, as some Lego enthusiasts may have gone down [this route](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/main.page) which would have been equally valid but a bit more artificial-feeling... Of course the final word is connected to the last word of the title too (but then you knew that already!).

Comment: @Stiv Right, that last bit was worth mentioning as well so edited it in!

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer, will have to revisit this later when I have more time.

The first group:

> ABORTION = ONTARIO + B
>  CHIANG MAI = MICHIGAN + A
>  ONRUSH = HURON + S
>  PRETORIUS = SUPERIOR + T
>
> These are four of the [Great Lakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Lakes) in the US. The four additional letters anagram to STAB, BATS, TABS...?

The second group:

> MALISM = MIMAS + L
>  OINKED = DIONE + K
>  PETUNIAS = IAPETUS + N
>  TITAN = TITAN + I
>
> These are four [moons of Saturn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moons_of_Saturn). The four additional letters anagram to LINK or KILN.

The third group:

> DURIANS = [DARIUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darius_the_Great) + N
>  FEDERAL = [ALFRED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_the_Great) + E
>  IN THE CLEAR = [CATHERINE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catherine_the_Great) + L
>  OH DEAR = [HEROD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herod_the_Great) + A
>
> These are four historical leaders who had "the Great" as their title. The four additional letters anagram to LANE or LEAN.

The remaining words:

> ESPECIAL = ECLIPSE + A?
>  MOULDED = MODULE + D?
>  SERAPH = SHAPE + R?
>  SYNDICATE = DISTANCE + Y?
>
> Unsure about this group. I originally had SHAPE and DISTANCE as two of the solutions because I thought DARIUS might be RADIUS and they were all geometry terms or something.  So it's possible some or all of these are wrong, there are certainly other anagrams possible.

Comment: Great work - you were so close to finishing it!